# Asp.Net MVC 3 JSON Model Binding not working

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am using MVC3 and that i know MVC3 support binding JSON literal to Action parameter. But i can't do it successfully;

I have a class name Tag

```
public class Tag
{
    public int tagId { get; set; }
    public string tagName { get; set; }
}
```

An Action on controller called Tag

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Tag(Tag tag)
    {
        // Here will be codes...
        return Json(new { success = 0 });
    }
```

Javascript code that send js object as JSON to my action

```
    var tag ={tagId:5,tagName:"hello"};
    $.ajax({
           url: "/image/tag",
           type: "POST",
           data: $.toJSON(tag),
           success: function (r) {
               if (r.success == 1) {
                   window.location = r.redirect;
               }
           }
```

Post Data that I see in Firebug Net tab

```
{"tagId":5,"tagName":"hello"}
```

Parameter name tag in Tag Action is not null but has values O for tagId and null for tagName.
What the problem in here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set the content type of the request to `application/json`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/image/tag',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: $.toJSON(tag),
    success: function (r) {
        if (r.success == 1) {
            window.location.href = r.redirect;
        }
    }
});
```

Ah, and you don't need to have your Tag model properties start with a lowercase letter:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

Remark 1: The `JavaScriptSerializer` class that ASP.NET MVC 3 uses behind the scenes is capable of properly handling this.

Remark 2: In your `Tag` action you seem to be returning the following JSON: `{"success":0}` whereas in your success AJAX callback you seem to be using some `r.redirect` property which doesn't exist.

Remark 3: Avoid naming your controller actions the same way as your view models. Normally action names should represent verbs (like `List`, `Save`, `Delete`, ...) whereas view models represent resources (`TagModel`, ...).

Comment: Tag is both a noun and a verb

Comment: Thanks Darin, i am facing with this problem about 1 hour you save me. Also thanks for your additional information

Comment: Remark 2. Success = 0 in the response so that block won't eval

Comment: You need to link json-js library (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) before using $.toJSON